# Enable Archiving failing on sde 9.3.1 and MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am trying to enable archiving and am getting this error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'archives_pk'.  Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SDE_archives'.

Is this saying that there is already a primary key in the dbo.SDE_archives table or there is already a primary key which is called archives_pk?  I deleted all versions, unregistered as versioned and moved all edits to base, then re-registered as versioned and tryed to enable archiving again with the same error.

My overall question is, how do I approach the dba because I don't have access directly to management studio on SQL Server 2008 nor would I know what I am doing?..Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By the error message you have mentioned, there seems to be a duplicate entry in the Archives table. Consult your DBA and delete the concerned record.

If feasible try to achieve a state zero compress and this should probably take care of the error.

Technical Article   HowTo:  Compress a versioned database to state 0
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/29160